# FileNotFoundException although the file is in place and the path is correct

Tags: java

I'm struggling to resolve a problem which seems very strange to me. I've looked trough at least five similar topics here on StackOverflow and neither of them provided an answer. But to the problem itself: I want to read in a file on app's startup. When I run the app in the IDE (IntelliJ Idea) everything is OK. Although when I build it with Gradle Java throws FileNotFoundException:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/user/IdeaProjects/time-keeper/build/libs/time-keeper-0.7-beta.jar!/data.csv (No such file or directory)
```

The path to the file is correct, the file exists, the jar has proper permissions.
The declaration:

```
File dataFile = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("data.csv").getFile());
Handle<TimeTask> dataHandle = new FileHandle(dataFile);
```

Comment: are you deploying the app to application server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as `data.csv` is a file itself, everything works. This is probably true as long as you run the application from within your IDE. In that case,

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("data.csv").getFile()
```

returns the path of a file on your file system. However, once gradle generates a JAR which contains the file `data.csv`, the above call produces

```
/home/user/IdeaProjects/time-keeper/build/libs/time-keeper-0.7-beta.jar!/data.csv
```

While this is technically the correct path (`data.csv` within the JAR), it is no longer a valid file system path. The `java.io.File` utilities cannot handle arbitrary URLs or files within archives. `data.csv` simply is no `File`, but an entry within an archive.

If you want to read the "file", you can use [`getSystemResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) which opens a resource (no matter whether it is a "real" file or not) as an `InputStream`.